# Decrease Query Execution Time

Tags: mysql, innodb, performance, query-performance

I have been having issues with 2 queries with query execution times up to 250 seconds for each query. The tables joined have each less than 10,000 rows, with exception to 2 tables that have around 60k and 30k rows each.

I am in learning stages of MySQL where I googled for writing each query. I googled about this and some of them suggest using an `inner join` is better, but I get the same result in both `inner join` and `left join`.

What can I do in order to get the results quickly.

**First Query**

This is not that complex but it is taking around 200 Seconds to Execute

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.ean
    ,p.isbn
    ,p.mpn
    ,p.sku
    ,p.minimum
    ,p.upc
    ,p.subtract
    ,p.sort_order
    ,p.model
    ,p.price AS normal_price
    ,p.IMAGE
    ,p.shipping
    ,p.weight
    ,p.weight_class_id
    ,p.date_modified
    ,p.quantity
    ,p.tax_class_id
    ,p.stock_status_id
    ,p.product_id AS id
    ,p.STATUS
    ,sta.NAME AS status_name
    ,pd.NAME AS products_name
    ,pd.description AS product_description
    ,pd.language_id
    ,pd.product_id
    ,pd.tag AS product_tags
    ,m.NAME AS manufacturer_name
    ,cd.NAME AS category_name
    ,cd.category_id
    ,cd.language_id
    ,st.store_id
FROM oc_product p
INNER JOIN oc_product_description pd ON p.product_id = pd.product_id
INNER JOIN oc_product_to_category p2c ON p.product_id = p2c.product_id
INNER JOIN oc_category c ON c.category_id
INNER JOIN oc_category_description cd ON cd.category_id = p2c.category_id
INNER JOIN oc_manufacturer m ON p.manufacturer_id = m.manufacturer_id
INNER JOIN oc_stock_status sta ON p.stock_status_id = sta.stock_status_id
INNER JOIN oc_product_to_store st ON p.product_id = st.product_id
WHERE p.STATUS = 1
    AND pd.language_id = 1
    AND sta.language_id = 1
    AND cd.language_id = 1
    AND st.store_id = 0
GROUP BY p.product_id
ORDER BY p.product_id ASC LIMIT 270
    ,10
```

[image: 1st Query Explain Results]

**Second Query**

This is taking around 240-250 Seconds

```
SELECT o.date_added AS DATE
    ,YEAR(o.date_added) AS year
    ,QUARTER(o.date_added) AS quarter
    ,MONTHNAME(o.date_added) AS month
    ,MIN(o.date_added) AS date_start
    ,MAX(o.date_added) AS date_end
    ,op.order_id
    ,op.product_id
    ,qa.order_product_id
    ,(
        SELECT p.IMAGE
        FROM oc_product p
        WHERE op.product_id = p.product_id
        ) AS IMAGE
    ,(
        SELECT p.sku
        FROM oc_product p
        WHERE op.product_id = p.product_id
        ) AS sku
    ,op.NAME
    ,op.model
    ,(
        SELECT cd.NAME
        FROM oc_category_description cd
            ,oc_category c
            ,oc_product_to_category p2c
        WHERE c.category_id = cd.category_id
            AND p2c.category_id = c.category_id
            AND cd.language_id = '1'
            AND op.product_id = p2c.product_id
        GROUP BY op.product_id
        ) AS category
    ,(
        SELECT p.manufacturer_id
        FROM oc_product p
        WHERE op.product_id = p.product_id
        ) AS manufacturer_id
    ,(
        SELECT m.NAME
        FROM oc_manufacturer m
            ,oc_product p
        WHERE p.manufacturer_id = m.manufacturer_id
            AND op.product_id = p.product_id
        ) AS manufacturer
    ,(
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT (
                    agd.NAME
                    ,'&nbsp;&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;&nbsp;'
                    ,ad.NAME
                    ,'&nbsp;&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;&nbsp;'
                    ,pa.TEXT
                    ) ORDER BY agd.NAME, ad.NAME, pa.TEXT ASC SEPARATOR '<br>')
        FROM oc_product_attribute pa
            ,oc_attribute_description ad
            ,oc_attribute a
            ,oc_attribute_group_description agd
        WHERE pa.language_id = '1'
            AND pa.product_id = op.product_id
            AND pa.attribute_id = ad.attribute_id
            AND ad.language_id = '1'
            AND ad.attribute_id = a.attribute_id
            AND a.attribute_group_id = agd.attribute_group_id
            AND agd.language_id = '1'
        ) AS attribute
    ,(
        SELECT p.STATUS
        FROM oc_product p
        WHERE op.product_id = p.product_id
        ) AS STATUS
    ,(
        SELECT p.quantity
        FROM oc_product p
        WHERE op.product_id = p.product_id
        ) AS stock_quantity
    ,(
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(IFNULL(pov.quantity, '&nbsp;') ORDER BY oo.order_option_id SEPARATOR '<br>')
        FROM oc_order_option oo
            ,oc_product_option_value pov
        WHERE op.order_product_id = oo.order_product_id
            AND op.product_id = pov.product_id
            AND pov.product_option_value_id = oo.product_option_value_id
        ) AS stock_oquantity
    ,SUM(op.quantity) AS sold_quantity
    ,op.price
    ,o.currency_code
    ,o.currency_value
    ,SUM(op.total) AS total_excl_vat
    ,SUM(op.tax * op.quantity) AS tax
    ,SUM(op.total + (op.tax * op.quantity)) AS total_incl_vat
    ,SUM(op.total) AS sales
    ,SUM(op.cost * op.quantity) AS costs
    ,SUM(op.total - op.cost * op.quantity) AS profit
    ,options
    ,oovalue
    ,ooname
    ,(
        SELECT SUM(op.quantity)
        FROM oc_order_product op
            ,oc_order o
        WHERE op.order_id = o.order_id
            AND (
                DATE (o.date_added) >= '2014-12-01'
                AND DATE (o.date_added) <= '2015-10-31'
                )
            AND o.order_status_id > 0
        ) AS sold_quantity_total
    ,(
        SELECT SUM(op.total)
        FROM oc_order_product op
            ,oc_order o
        WHERE op.order_id = o.order_id
            AND (
                DATE (o.date_added) >= '2014-12-01'
                AND DATE (o.date_added) <= '2015-10-31'
                )
            AND o.order_status_id > 0
        ) AS total_excl_vat_total
    ,(
        SELECT SUM(op.tax * op.quantity)
        FROM oc_order_product op
            ,oc_order o
        WHERE op.order_id = o.order_id
            AND (
                DATE (o.date_added) >= '2014-12-01'
                AND DATE (o.date_added) <= '2015-10-31'
                )
            AND o.order_status_id > 0
        ) AS tax_total
    ,(
        SELECT SUM(op.total + (op.tax * op.quantity))
        FROM oc_order_product op
            ,oc_order o
        WHERE op.order_id = o.order_id
            AND (
                DATE (o.date_added) >= '2014-12-01'
                AND DATE (o.date_added) <= '2015-10-31'
                )
            AND o.order_status_id > 0
        ) AS total_incl_vat_total
    ,(
        SELECT SUM(op.total)
        FROM oc_order_product op
            ,oc_order o
        WHERE op.order_id = o.order_id
            AND (
                DATE (o.date_added) >= '2014-12-01'
                AND DATE (o.date_added) <= '2015-10-31'
                )
            AND o.order_status_id > 0
        ) AS sales_total
    ,(
        SELECT SUM(op.cost * op.quantity)
        FROM oc_order_product op
            ,oc_order o
        WHERE op.order_id = o.order_id
            AND (
                DATE (o.date_added) >= '2014-12-01'
                AND DATE (o.date_added) <= '2015-10-31'
                )
            AND o.order_status_id > 0
        ) AS costs_total
    ,(
        SELECT SUM(op.total - op.cost * op.quantity)
        FROM oc_order_product op
            ,oc_order o
        WHERE op.order_id = o.order_id
            AND (
                DATE (o.date_added) >= '2014-12-01'
                AND DATE (o.date_added) <= '2015-10-31'
                )
            AND o.order_status_id > 0
        ) AS profit_total
FROM (
    SELECT oo.order_product_id
        ,GROUP_CONCAT(NAME, value, type ORDER BY NAME, value, type) AS options
        ,GROUP_CONCAT(value SEPARATOR '<br>') AS oovalue
        ,GROUP_CONCAT(NAME SEPARATOR ':<br>') AS ooname
    FROM oc_order_option oo
    WHERE (
            type = 'radio'
            OR type = 'checkbox'
            OR type = 'select'
            OR type = 'image'
            OR type = 'colour'
            OR type = 'size'
            OR type = 'multiple'
            )
    GROUP BY order_product_id
    ) qa
    ,oc_order_product op
    ,oc_order o
WHERE op.order_product_id = qa.order_product_id
    AND op.order_id = o.order_id
    AND (
        DATE (o.date_added) >= '2014-12-01'
        AND DATE (o.date_added) <= '2015-10-31'
        )
    AND o.order_status_id > 0
GROUP BY options
    ,op.product_id

UNION ALL

SELECT o.date_added AS DATE
    ,YEAR(o.date_added) AS year
    ,QUARTER(o.date_added) AS quarter
    ,MONTHNAME(o.date_added) AS month
    ,MIN(o.date_added) AS date_start
    ,MAX(o.date_added) AS date_end
    ,op.order_id
    ,op.product_id
    ,op.order_product_id
    ,(
        SELECT p.IMAGE
        FROM oc_product p
        WHERE op.product_id = p.product_id
        ) AS IMAGE
    ,(
        SELECT p.sku
        FROM oc_product p
        WHERE op.product_id = p.product_id
        ) AS sku
    ,op.NAME
    ,op.model
    ,(
        SELECT cd.NAME
        FROM oc_category_description cd
            ,oc_category c
            ,oc_product_to_category p2c
        WHERE c.category_id = cd.category_id
            AND p2c.category_id = c.category_id
            AND cd.language_id = '1'
            AND op.product_id = p2c.product_id
        GROUP BY op.product_id
        ) AS category
    ,(
        SELECT p.manufacturer_id
        FROM oc_product p
        WHERE op.product_id = p.product_id
        ) AS manufacturer_id
    ,(
        SELECT m.NAME
        FROM oc_manufacturer m
            ,oc_product p
        WHERE p.manufacturer_id = m.manufacturer_id
            AND op.product_id = p.product_id
        ) AS manufacturer
    ,(
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT (
                    agd.NAME
                    ,'&nbsp;&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;&nbsp;'
                    ,ad.NAME
                    ,'&nbsp;&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;&nbsp;'
                    ,pa.TEXT
                    ) ORDER BY agd.NAME, ad.NAME, pa.TEXT ASC SEPARATOR '<br>')
        FROM oc_product_attribute pa
            ,oc_attribute_description ad
            ,oc_attribute a
            ,oc_attribute_group_description agd
        WHERE pa.language_id = '1'
            AND pa.product_id = op.product_id
            AND pa.attribute_id = ad.attribute_id
            AND ad.language_id = '1'
            AND ad.attribute_id = a.attribute_id
            AND a.attribute_group_id = agd.attribute_group_id
            AND agd.language_id = '1'
        ) AS attribute
    ,(
        SELECT p.STATUS
        FROM oc_product p
        WHERE op.product_id = p.product_id
        ) AS STATUS
    ,(
        SELECT p.quantity
        FROM oc_product p
        WHERE op.product_id = p.product_id
        ) AS stock_quantity
    ,'' AS stock_oquantity
    ,SUM(op.quantity) AS sold_quantity
    ,op.price
    ,o.currency_code
    ,o.currency_value
    ,SUM(op.total) AS total_excl_vat
    ,SUM(op.tax * op.quantity) AS tax
    ,SUM(op.total + (op.tax * op.quantity)) AS total_incl_vat
    ,SUM(op.total) AS sales
    ,SUM(op.cost * op.quantity) AS costs
    ,SUM(op.total - op.cost * op.quantity) AS profit
    ,'' AS options
    ,'' AS oovalue
    ,'' AS ooname
    ,(
        SELECT SUM(op.quantity)
        FROM oc_order_product op
            ,oc_order o
        WHERE op.order_id = o.order_id
            AND (
                DATE (o.date_added) >= '2014-12-01'
                AND DATE (o.date_added) <= '2015-10-31'
                )
            AND o.order_status_id > 0
        ) AS sold_quantity_total
    ,(
        SELECT SUM(op.total)
        FROM oc_order_product op
            ,oc_order o
        WHERE op.order_id = o.order_id
            AND (
                DATE (o.date_added) >= '2014-12-01'
                AND DATE (o.date_added) <= '2015-10-31'
                )
            AND o.order_status_id > 0
        ) AS total_excl_vat_total
    ,(
        SELECT SUM(op.tax * op.quantity)
        FROM oc_order_product op
            ,oc_order o
        WHERE op.order_id = o.order_id
            AND (
                DATE (o.date_added) >= '2014-12-01'
                AND DATE (o.date_added) <= '2015-10-31'
                )
            AND o.order_status_id > 0
        ) AS tax_total
    ,(
        SELECT SUM(op.total + (op.tax * op.quantity))
        FROM oc_order_product op
            ,oc_order o
        WHERE op.order_id = o.order_id
            AND (
                DATE (o.date_added) >= '2014-12-01'
                AND DATE (o.date_added) <= '2015-10-31'
                )
            AND o.order_status_id > 0
        ) AS total_incl_vat_total
    ,(
        SELECT SUM(op.total)
        FROM oc_order_product op
            ,oc_order o
        WHERE op.order_id = o.order_id
            AND (
                DATE (o.date_added) >= '2014-12-01'
                AND DATE (o.date_added) <= '2015-10-31'
                )
            AND o.order_status_id > 0
        ) AS sales_total
    ,(
        SELECT SUM(op.cost * op.quantity)
        FROM oc_order_product op
            ,oc_order o
        WHERE op.order_id = o.order_id
            AND (
                DATE (o.date_added) >= '2014-12-01'
                AND DATE (o.date_added) <= '2015-10-31'
                )
            AND o.order_status_id > 0
        ) AS costs_total
    ,(
        SELECT SUM(op.total - op.cost * op.quantity)
        FROM oc_order_product op
            ,oc_order o
        WHERE op.order_id = o.order_id
            AND (
                DATE (o.date_added) >= '2014-12-01'
                AND DATE (o.date_added) <= '2015-10-31'
                )
            AND o.order_status_id > 0
        ) AS profit_total
FROM oc_order_product op
    ,oc_order o
WHERE op.order_id = o.order_id
    AND

IF (
        op.order_product_id NOT IN (
            SELECT order_product_id
            FROM oc_order_option
            )
        ,op.order_product_id NOT IN (
            SELECT order_product_id
            FROM oc_order_option
            )
        ,op.order_product_id IN (
            SELECT order_product_id
            FROM oc_order_option
            GROUP BY order_product_id
            HAVING SUM(product_option_value_id) = 0
            )
        )
    AND (
        DATE (o.date_added) >= '2014-12-01'
        AND DATE (o.date_added) <= '2015-10-31'
        )
    AND o.order_status_id > 0 GROUP BY op.product_id ORDER BY sold_quantity DESC
    ,sales DESC;
```

[image: 2nd Query Explain Results]

Please note that when i checked profiling option 98% of the time taken is for copying to tmp table.

the heap table and tmp table size is:

`SET max_heap_table_size = 1024 * 1024 * 132;`

SET tmp_table_size = 1024 * 1024 * 132;

Answer (score 1):

In the first query, "pagination via OFFSET" is at least part of the performance problem.  In your example, your query must scan 270+10 rows to find the 10 needed.  If, instead, you "remembered where you left off", you might be able to look at only 10 rows.  [*More discussion*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination).

(In the first query, you used `JOIN .. ON` syntax - good.  Please do the same for the second.)

Add composite indexes where appropriate.  For example: `pd`: `INDEX(language_id, product_id)`.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can discuss this further.

With all the 'attribute' and 'language' tables, I suspect this is an EAV schema that is "over-normalized".  Again, seeing the schema will help discuss this.

I see two subqueries referencing oc_product to get two columns (IMAGE and sku).  A JOIN to oc_product would probably be more efficient.

Don't hide date_added inside a function (`DATE()`), Instead do `o.date_added >= '2014-12-01' AND o.date_added < '2015-11-01'`.

In the `EXPLAIN`, the `59780` together with `Using index` suggests that it did a full index scan to find the answer.  Probably need a better index (and not hide the column in a function).

`IN ( SELECT ... ) is inefficient, can it be written another way?`

Here's a big mistake that is hurting the first query:

```
INNER JOIN oc_category c ON c.category_id
```

Perhaps you meant

```
INNER JOIN oc_category c ON c.category_id = p.category_id
```

That showed up in the `EXPLAIN` as an unexpectedly big number of rows for `c`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I cant believe it. The first query time went down from 200+ seconds to 0.34 seconds when i added  `INNER JOIN oc_category c ON c.category_id = p.category_id `.

Comment: Yep.  You were looking through 1K rows instead of 1.  (See the `1021` on the last line of the `EXPLAIN`.)